# `bundle exec rake` or `rake`? What about `Rake::TestTask`?

Tags: ruby, testing, rake, bundler, rake-task

It looks to me strange to call `bundle exec rake` or `bundle exec make`: why not

```
bundle exec bundle exec rake
```

then?

I though i should be able to require and use Bundler from inside a Rakefile (or Makefile).  However, i cannot find how to run tests with the correct group of gems, the following does not work:

```rb
# Rakefile
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  require 'bundler'
  Bundler.setup(:default, :test)  # this has no effect
  t.test_files = FileList['test.rb']
end
```

Could someone help me with setting up the Rake test task correctly, or explain the philosophical reason to use `bundle exec rake`?

Note that `bundle exec rake` requires adding `gem rake` to the Gemfile.

Answer (score 3):

The whole purpose of `bundle exec` is to run whatever follows, in the context of your project's `Gemfile`.

Without it, a call to `rake` could use a system-wide installed rake and/or gems. This does not allow for a fine-grained control over which version of each gem is being used in each project.  This becomes particularly relevant when you develop (or serve in a production environment) multiple ruby projects that use different versions of the same gems.

Bundler allows your project to be self-contained without any assumptions on system available dependencies.

That being said, you could create a shell alias that prefixes what you want with `bundle exec`. My zsh configuration (with bundler plugin enabled), for example, provides me with the `be` shorthand for `bundle exec`.

Comment: Yes, i know this, but why couldn't the Rakefile (or the Makefile, if i am using GNU Make and not Rake) take care of this?  I have not heard about running `make`, for example, through another command.

Comment: Because they do not make any assumption that you are actually using bundler. As useful and sometimes essential `bundler` is, you could opt to run a ruby project without it.

Comment: Why can i make the assumption that i am using Rake (by including `gem rake` in Gemfile), but cannot make assumptions that i am using Bundler?  If i do opt to use Bundler, why not automate it in the Rakefile or in the Makefile?

Comment: `Rakefile` is an independent file that is picked up every time you issue a `rake` command. This does not require you to use bundle or anything else for that matter. If you decide to use bundle in order to handle your dependencies, it makes sense that you use `bundle exec ...`. Rake (and Rakefile) is still agnostic of bundler. That means that I could issue a `rake` command which will consult `Rakefile` without even having the `bundler` gem installed.

Comment: If i want to have Rake tasks which always use bundled gems, and other tasks that do not depend on bundler and possibly use system gems or executables, then i would need to call some tasks always with `bundle exec` and some always without.

Comment: Yes that makes sense to me. Plus you could have multiple developers/maintainers with their own setup who like to use, or not to, bundler. As I said you could even alias `rake` with `bundle exec rake` to avoid the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

About `Bundler.setup(:default, :test)` having no effect, it seems to me that this could be caused by a Bundler bug, for example by [this one](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3009).

I think that it is a bug because `Bundler.setup` is not really ignored.

Consider the following setup:

```rb
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'
gem 'rack-test', :group => :test
```

```rb
# Rakefile
require 'rake/testtask'
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  require 'bundler'
  Bundler.setup(:default)
  t.test_files = FileList['test.rb']
end
```

```rb
# test.rb
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup(:default)
require 'rack/test'
```

Unexpectedly, `rake test` runs without error.

If i comment out `Bundler.setup(:default)` in the Rakefile, then it cannot require rack/test anymore.

Comment: The [bug](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3009) is fixed, but i have not tried  yet to see if `Bundler.setup(:default, :test)` would work now.